# 2000s (?) black and white comic about a training academy for teens with psychic powers, ranked by "psych level"

Tags: story-identification, comics, young-adult, space, psychic

The story was set in some sort of sci-fi school or training academy. The characters were somewhere in their teens, and I think the main character was a blonde girl. The characters had some sort of psychic powers but I don't remember which exactly, and it may have varied per person. I remember the strengths of their powers were measured using something called 'psych levels'.

I remember there was one scene where the characters were sitting in a cafeteria and when someone criticizes the school, one girl, who I think might have been black, says that she was the daughter of the vice-president of some planet, and some other guy was the child of coal miners or something on another planet, and if not for the school they never would have met.

Also, I remember another scene where the principal or some school official was talking with someone else about deciding to let a student join the academy. The prospective student's psychic powers made him very good at martial arts, but he had a 'psych level' of 3.5 which the principal said barely qualified him as a psychic. I think the students were being trained to fight.

Also, there might have been a scene where after returning from training, the main character talks to a much younger girl, another student I think. And I think the young girl was amazed by how powerful the main character who had a ‘psych level’ of like 10 (?) was. I think the young girl may have been in a lower grade or something similar and studying to be in the same program/grade as the main character.

I'm also pretty sure the school was some sort of space ship or building in space, because I don't remember the characters going outside the school, or there being grounds outside the school. This also makes me pretty certain the school was something like a boarding school, and not not one where they returned home every night.

Also, I feel like the story may have been leaning towards 'the school is not what it seems with the teachers/organization in charge having some sort of ulterior motive'.

The comic may have been a manga, but I don't remember. But I'm pretty sure that the art was detailed, polished, and fairly modern. I'm also almost certain that the comic was in black and white, but I don't know about the cover. I read the story around ~2014 so I don't think it's super old. I also think it was targeted toward a younger, maybe YA audience, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It isn't black and white (color wise, maybe philosophically it is), but [A Certain Magical Index](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/LightNovel/ACertainMagicalIndex) is a Manga which has a city studying everyone with Psychic powers, and everyone is given a ranking. It was also in the mid-late 2000s.

Comment: Jack B Nimble, it sounds similar but I don’t think it’s what I’m looking for. I think the main character was a girl with long blonde hair, but my memory may be faulty.